# Function pointers with default parameters in C++

Tags: c++, function-pointers, default-parameters, function-signature

How does C++ handle function pointers in relation to functions with defaulted parameters?

If I have:

```
void foo(int i, float f = 0.0f);
void bar(int i, float f);


void (*func_ptr1)(int);
void (*func_ptr2)(int, float);
void (*func_ptr3)(int, float = 10.0f);
```

Which function pointers can I use in relation to which function?

Comment: C++ does not allow default arguments in function pointer declarations. Your `func_ptr3` declaration is ill-formed. So there's nothing to "handle" here.

Answer (score 36):

Both `foo()` and `bar()` can only be assigned to `func_ptr2`.

*§8.3.6/2*:

> A default argument is not part of the type of a function. *[Example:*

```
int f(int = 0);

void h() {
    int j = f(1);
    int k = f(); // OK, means f(0)
}

int (*p1)(int) = &f; 
int (*p2)() = &f; // error: type mismatch
```

> *--end example]*

Comment: because default parameter are actually implemented by compiler ?

Comment: Because default arguments are not taken into consideration for the type, i.e. `int f(int)` and `int g(int=0)` have the same type.

Comment: That would rule out func_ptr1. What about func_ptr3?

Comment: That also rules out #3 - default arguments are only allowed for function declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Default argument cannot be provided for pointers to functions.